# Two dimensional string array in java

Tags: java, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I am new to java please help me with this issue.
I have a string lets say

```
adc|def|efg||hij|lmn|opq
```

now i split this string and store it in an array using

```
String output[] = stringname.split("||");
```

now i again need to split that based on '|'
and i need something like

`arr[1][]=adc,arr[2][]=def` 
and so on so that i can access each and every element.
something like a 2 dimensional string array.
I heard this could be done using **Arraylist**, but i am not able to figure it out.
Please help.

Comment: sorry, expected is arr[0][0]=adc,arr[0][1]=def and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your solution except names[0][0]="adc", names[0][1]="def" and so on:

```
String str = "adc|def|efg||hij|lmn|opq";
String[] obj = str.split("\\|\\|");
    int i=0;
    String[][] names = new String[obj.length][]; 

    for(String temp:obj){
        names[i++]=temp.split("\\|");

    }
List<String[]> yourList = Arrays.asList(names);// yourList will be 2D arraylist.
System.out.println(yourList.get(0)[0]); // This will print adc.
System.out.println(yourList.get(0)[1]); // This will print def.
System.out.println(yourList.get(0)[2]); // This will print efg.
               // Similarly you can fetch other elements by yourList.get(1)[index]
```

Comment: Why are you escaping pipes?

Comment: I tried without escaping pipes but then its not spliting string properly. That's why I add escaping pipes and bingo..its working. :)

Comment: And where is the `ArrayList` part of the question?!

Comment: But how do i extract each and every string from the name array? It says null.

Comment: @R.J I forgot to paste last line. ;) @Magic - It's `names` array, not `name`, and BTW how you are accessing it?

Comment: @VimalBera i tried to access it like a Two dimensional array, i am not sure if it is right.

Comment: It asked me to cast to ArrayList.                              `ArrayList<String[]> yourList = (ArrayList<String[]>) Arrays.asList(names);
        
        for(int j=0;j<1;j++)
        {
            System.out.println(yourList.get(0));
        }`

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is:

```
String str[]="adc|def|efg||hij|lmn|opq".split("||");
String str2[]=str[0].split("|");
str2 will be containing abc, def , efg
// arrays have toList() method like:

Arrays.asList(any_array);
```

Comment: U mean to say use seperate arrays to sub split it based on '|'?? but the numbe rof splits produced varies.

Comment: i meant how you can access them and according to your need you can loop around them and put them into array, arrayList whatever you want, i showed how to slit them

Answer (score 0):

Can hardly understand your problem...

I guess you may want to use a 2-dimenison ArrayList : `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>`

```
String input = "adc|def|efg||hij|lmn|opq";
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> res = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
for(String strs:input.split("||")){
    ArrayList<String> strList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(String str:strs.split("|"))
        strList.add(str);
    res.add(strList);
}
```