# Create a two dimensional string array anArray[2][2]

Tags: java, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

I'm currently on a self learning Java course and am completely stumped at one of my assignments, can anyone give me some pointers please? Bear in mind that I am completely new to Java so I need it to be as simple as.

The question: 
3. Create a Java program called TwoDimArray and implement the following:

```
Create a two dimensional string array anArray[2][2].
Assign values to the 2d array containing any Country and associated colour. 

    Example:

    France Blue 

    Ireland Green 

Output the values of the 2d array using nested for loops.
```

The code I have come up with that is also not working:

```
public class TwoDimArray {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    char Ireland = 0;
    char Green = 1;
    char England = 2;
    char White = 3;
    char firstArray[][] = {{Ireland},{Green}};
    char secondArray[][] = {{England},{White}};

    System.out.println();
    display(firstArray);
    System.out.println();
    display(secondArray);

  }

  public static void display(char a[][]) {
    for (char row = 0; row < a .length; row++) {
      for (char col = 0; col < a [row] .length; col++) {
        System.out.print(a[row][col] + " ");
      }

      System.out.println();
    }
  }
}
```

Can anyone give me some pointers? I can't seem to find anything that helps me on the web so thought I'd come here and ask.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: _"Create a two dimensional string array"_. Did you do that ?

Comment: you can make arrays of String, too.

Comment: I have no idea how I missed that at all, I'll get on that. Thanks guys.

Comment: I think this will help you

[Two Dimensional String Array][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19173396/two-dimensional-string-array-in-java

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like this is what you want

```
    int columns = 2;
    int rows = 2;

    String[][] newArray = new String[columns][rows];
    newArray[0][0] = "France";
    newArray[0][1] = "Blue";

    newArray[1][0] = "Ireland";
    newArray[1][1] = "Green";

    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++){
            System.out.println(newArray[i][j]);
        }
    }
```

Here I'll explain the code:

This declares the size of your new 2D array. In Java (and most programming languages), your first value starts at 0, so the size of this array is actually 2 rows by 2 columns

```
    int columns = 2;
    int rows = 2;
```

Here you are using the type `String[][]` to create a new 2D array with the size defined by `[rows][columns]`.

```
    String[][] newArray = new String[columns][rows];
```

You assign the values by its placement within the array.

```
    newArray[0][0] = "France";
    newArray[0][1] = "Blue";

    newArray[1][0] = "Ireland";
    newArray[1][1] = "Green";
```

Looping through `i` would loop through the rows, and looping through `j` would loop through the columns. This code loops through all rows and columns and prints out the values in each index.

```
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++){
            System.out.println(newArray[i][j]);
        }
    }
```

Alternatively, assignment can be a one-liner:

```
    String[][] newArray = {{"France", "Blue"}, {"Ireland", "Green"}};
```

But I don't like this way, as when you start dealing with larger sets of data (like 10,000+ points of data with many columns), hardcoding it in like this can be rough.

Comment: My homework for you is to not write it procedurally but write it objectively ;-). I think that's what the exercise would have wanted too.

Comment: Any reply? Feedback? Questions?

Comment: Np. Now do it objectively! I'll start you off with the instance variable as `String[][] newArray`.

Comment: Why is it `String[][] newArray = new String[columns][rows];` and not `String[][] newArray = new String[rows][columns];`? I thought rows go before columns in initializing and accessing a 2d array.